# Apache camel-cxf with POJO dataFormat

Tags: cxf, apache-camel

I have following route:

```
<route>
  <from uri="cxf:bean:MyBean" />
  <process ref="myProcessor" />
</route>
```

I need to process SOAP message but at the beginnig of each call I have to save original SOAP message into database (whole envelope with headers and body).
As you can see I want to use cxf in POJO dataFormat.

I can't find any information why my original SOAP message is modified (whole body section is removed, and converter to POJO). Is it possible to get original SOAP message in my case?

Thanks

Comment: I found appropriate solution - http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Getting-entire-Soap-Message-with-header-and-body-in-Payload-mode-td5753162.html

Comment: Please add an appropriate answer below and mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor` is a good example how to extract original SOAP content and properties. See [github.com](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/interceptor/LoggingInInterceptor.java) for source code.

Here is example how to store SOAP content in CXF Message (`bos` is CachedOutputStream from LoggingInInterceptor source code):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(bos.getInputStream(), baos);
message.getExchange().put("OriginalSoap", baos.toByteArray());
```

Here is how to retrieve stored SOAP content from org.apache.camel.Exchange:

```
byte[] content = (byte[])exchange.getIn()
        .getHeader(CxfConstants.CAMEL_CXF_MESSAGE, org.apache.cxf.message.Message.class)
        .getExchange()
        .get("OriginalPayload");
```

Content storing and retrieving based on solution from http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Getting-entire-Soap-Message-with-header-and-body-in-Payload-mode-td5753162.html